# will upgrading python version make older code can not be runned

Tags: python, python-3.x, upgrade

I know it is obvious if the case is upgrading a library or package, but what about upgrading the python (by the way by 'upgrading' i meant like 3.7 to 3.10 not from 2 to 3), does the older (python 3) code still work on my computer or is there a case where it doesn't work?

Comment: Almost surely, your code will be compatible on minor version upgrades of python. However, this is not guaranteed and you could hit some (usually fairly esoteric) edge case as Python does introduce backwards-incompatible changes on minor versions.

Comment: It's a bug if forwards compatibility is broken within the same major release series, but we can't tell you bugs are impossible. _Rare_, certainly. _Impossible_, no.

Comment: In general, when it matters, you should be using tools that manage your software loadout on a per-project basis instead of using globally-installed software in the first place. See [Nix](https://nixos.org/) for an example -- you can have one project using Python 3.8, another on 3.9, another on 3.9 but compiled against musl libc instead of glibc, etc.